# App crashing when setting UITabBarDelegate to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Having an issue with my app crashing when I try and set the UITabBarDelegate to self in subclass of `UIViewController`. I have a `UITabBarViewController` with several TabItems linked to View Controllers. One of those View Controllers is `HomeViewController`. I have the following code in `HomeViewController`:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.translucent = false
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.delegate = self //This is causing crash
    }
}
```

If I delete the `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.delegate = self` line everything works fine and my tabBar behaves as expected, but when I re-add that line I get the following crash:

```
ibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Not entirely sure how to resolve this. Have found some other answers on SO but they still seemed a little unclear on what the process is to make this work.

Thanks!

Comment: catch the exception and print the description of the exception using this
`print(exception.localizedDescription)`
Then please show what it says

Comment: Your UITabBarViewController is already the delegate to your UITabBar. Why do you need to set the delegate to another viewController?

Comment: I have a method within HomeViewController that I would like to execute when the tabBar Item "Home" is touched. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: see my answer and then let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UITabBarViewController is already a delegate to your UITabBar. Instead of making your viewController your tabBarDelegate, use your tabBarViewController and put your logic there.

You can do something like this. In the tabBarViewController's didSelectItem delegate method

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem)
{
    let index = tabBar.items?.indexOf(item)

    if (index == /*the required index of HomeViewController*/)
    {
         let homeVC = self.viewControllers.objectAtIndex(index) as! HomeViewController
         homeVC.myMethod()
    }

}
```

Comment: Glad to have been a help